# Can `monit` send alerts to an HTTP endpoint (instead of email only)?

Tags: monit

I'd like to configure Monit to deliver 'fail' and 'success' notifications via its alerting system; the global alerting system seems only to support email notifications, and there doesn't seem to be a way to configure 'if alert, do this; on recovery, do that' type of logic.

I'm new to Monit; is my understanding correct?

What I need to be able to do is to signal my monitoring system, preferably via an HTTP endpoint, on success/fail events.

I can do this individually via 'program' checks that provide a return code that can be used to trigger an external script; I'd prefer to do this globally, however, so that I can configure a single 'alert' that applies to all services.

The alert would then communicate a binary 'success' or 'fail' message with a payload identifying the problem (in the case of alerts).

Is that functionality possible in Monit?

I've been trying to find a way to implement what I've described but have not been able to.

UPDATE 2020-06-07
I think I’m might not be explaining the problem correctly.

The basic idea is that I want a single “check” on each server that tells me whether or not any Monit services are in a “down” state. I use a third-party service to monitor that “check” (think Cronitor).

I was able to automate this with a shell script and a cron job by evaluating the output of `monit report` and it’s working pretty well; I was initially attempting to do this in Monit (trying to get it to alert to an HTTP endpoint with this basic check, versus sending an email) but I was unable to find a way.

Comment: i am unsure but usually any program can usually exec a command and so curl would maybe your choice?

Comment: Yeah, `curl` does actually work; ‘check program’ didn’t seem to work too consistently with these cron-style checks though (may have been my fault as I’m learning Monit). I ended up with a script that first checks that Monit is running and then checks against service status per my update today (above).